# Segmentation Fault: 11 with no files specified

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, segmentation-fault, swift3

I'm having a bit of an odd error. When I build my fairly big iOS Swift 3 project with any compiler optimizations on, I get a segmentation fault. There aren't any specific files actually named to help me find the cause of this problem. Instead, it prints out all of the compiler arguments (a list of every file in the project). The closest thing I have to information is the following:

```
0  swift                    0x000000010c20ea3d PrintStackTraceSignalHandler(void*) + 45
1  swift                    0x000000010c20e466 SignalHandler(int) + 470
2  libsystem_platform.dylib 0x00007fffca153bba _sigtramp + 26
3  libsystem_platform.dylib 0x00007fb870004600 _sigtramp + 2783644256
4  swift                    0x000000010962d3fe swift::irgen::IRGenerator::emitGlobalTopLevel() + 1790
5  swift                    0x00000001096ef4e2 swift::performIRGeneration(swift::IRGenOptions&, swift::ModuleDecl*, swift::SILModule*, llvm::StringRef, llvm::LLVMContext&) + 1554
6  swift                    0x00000001095bcd72 performCompile(swift::CompilerInstance&, swift::CompilerInvocation&, llvm::ArrayRef<char const*>, int&, swift::FrontendObserver*) + 24050
7  swift                    0x00000001095b4f70 swift::performFrontend(llvm::ArrayRef<char const*>, char const*, void*, swift::FrontendObserver*) + 17856
8  swift                    0x000000010957193e main + 8302
9  libdyld.dylib            0x00007fffc9f46255 start + 1
10 libdyld.dylib            0x000000000000011f start + 906731211
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. If there is any more information that I left out that could be useful (there isn't much given), just tell me. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was using trying to use a struct as a singleton. I turned on single-file optimization to get a better look at the problem which pointed me to the file with the struct. From there, I changed this struct to a class so it could still be used as a singleton, and the code now compiles.